# Is there any way to get deleted logs using ContentResolver or ContentProvider

Tags: android

```
public void getLogs() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Cursor managedCursor =getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    eLogs.setText(sb);
}
```

This is my code to get Call logs using ContentResolver and i am getting the accurate result which contains the existing call history of about 20 days.
Is there a way or query to get deleted call history/logs. if not then how can i achieve the expected results.
P.S: i need all of the history(at-least call logs of past 6 months) including deleted/removed logs.